# Get element text before page reloads in ASP.net web forms 

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am unfortunately having to work with asp.net web forms. I have a label that has a different Text property every time the page loads. I have a button that is clicked. I have double clicked on the button and it has shown me a code view.

I get a reference to the label via labelID.Text, but it refers to the value of the text that is about to be displayed on the next page load. How would I get the text of the value when the button was actually clicked?  Or is web forms not advanced enough for that.

Comment: unfortunate? hmm...i have half a mind to down vote this. and i doubt even though webforms is not not one of the best out there whether you know enough to judge that. framework is your friend :)

Comment: unfortunate because it combines the view logic with business logic, involves "drap and drop" controls that are hard to maintain, and tries to promote Microsoft technologies instead of html/css/javascript.

Comment: oh and it tries to pretend the web works like a windows desktop application... great.

Comment: it's only does that if you choose to do it that way. It's possible to to have clear separation of logic if you design it right. It pushes MS technology as much as mvc does. after all, they're built on the same thing. It does have some oddities (themes?) I'll grant you that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search where the labelID.Text is modified (maybe Page_Load event), and save the text before in a global variable.

Comment: what counds terrible? please elaborate.

Comment: well, it worked. But am I seriously supposed to fill the Web Form with variable declarations (assuming I need more global variables).

Comment: well you need to store the value somewhere. it's only a class variable

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like on every page load or postback, somewhere there is code which applies a new value to labelID.Text.  Where is that work being done?  Page_Load?

In any case, wherever that work is being done, you most likely have access to both the existing text value of the control, and the new text value you're about to give it.